# how do you say in 文言 "I became an eunuch because of the sex and drugs and tang-poems, not because i love the king and his rotten offspring"?

Tags: grammar

could you make some annotation with regard to the grammar needed to translate.

Comment: This is the best translation request I've ever seen.

Comment: I wonder what kind of sex has driven you to become an eunuch...

Comment: Hmmm that sounds certainly like Lord Varys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

非以王及其腐產而因情酒唐詩為監也

This is always a mine field… for example, one could observe that narcotics as we know them have not been very prominent in Chinese culture, at least not before the forced opium trade, so drugs would be wine.

Comment: does 监 have the meaning of eunuch in 文言文? I would think of something like 宦(者)

Comment: Or 内侍, 中涓, 阉人, 寺人 and a myriad other forms. 阉人 and similar are the oldest forms, from Zhou onwards. 宦官 is more prominent in the early dynastic period, while 太监 becomes common from Liao and later dynasties, especially in Qing. It is a euphemism for ”functionary”.

Comment: Yes, I know that 太监 becomes common in later dynasties. Still, is it all right to use a single character 监?

Comment: It is an interesting question to what extent bound forms in modern Chinese are free in classical Chinese, given the latter's preference for single syllable forms. Both 宦 and 监 are bound in modern Chinese.

康熙 states this, however: 又宦寺亦曰監。《史記·秦本紀》衞鞅因景監求見孝公。《註》監，奄人也。 That is, 监 in unbound form.

Answer (score 3):

> 余入宫为奴，盖因唐诗酒色。今上昏庸，诸子腐败，皆不足爱也。

@倪阔乐's answer looks like a machine translation of the original English text. Ancient Chinese people don't talk like that.

"情" is emotion, not sex.

"腐產" as rotten offspring? Not even close.

Comment: Ancient Chinese people don't talk at all, and when they did, they mostly used the vernacular.

In classical Chinese, 情, 性, 色 can be used interchangeably, and this is also true in modern Chinese: 情欲, 性欲, 色欲 all mean sexual lust.

情者，人之欲也。人欲之谓情。

Philosophically, 情 and 性 are two manifestations of 阴阳:

性生于阳以理执。情生于阴以系念。

Thus 情 has more a passive or female connotation, but it is also a euphemism for the more active and male variant.

腐败 originally meant rotten in the biological sense, and only later took on a more abstract meaning. Using it in the sense of "corrupt" is fairly modern (late Qing).

Comment: @倪阔乐 “酒色” as an idiom means strictly “liquer and sex”, with your self-invented “情酒” no one is sure if it's sex or something else. “腐产” is another such invention. “产” can be “production” or “wealth”, seldom does it mean “offspring”. But above all, the colossal single sentence structure just isn't classical Chinese at all.

Comment: “腐败” is no different from “腐”, so I don't think there is a disagreement.

Comment: I forgot to add a double quote to the word talk. They do “talk” in classical literatures.